# How to change the User name and Password of admin account

Tags: admin, username, account

By default i have selected the Username of admin account as "admin" , of the Wordpress CMS while installing wordpress first time. Now i want to deploy the webpage : considering the security precautions , i want to change User name and Password of admin account. Can anyone guide me on this.
The database for the User_login appears like this haven't see the MD5  code for the user_name ?

Thanks

[image: PHP_Myadmin Panel]

[image: User_Login Field in Database]

Answer (score 1):

Create new admin account using proper name and password. Login as new admin and delete old admin account. You are done.

Suggestions to use phpMyAdmin MD5 hash are out of date. This doesn't work anymore:

[image]

Comment: Hi:any detailed step by step approach.

Comment: MD5 approach is actually supported and will probably continue to be as it is the only way to change passwords by direct access to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do it is go into the WP admin (login), create a new user then delete the user one that is set as Admin.

Comment: you mean the database ? or php file ?

Comment: When you login to the admin of the website, eg www.mywebsite.com/wp-admin 

Then go to USERS > ALL USERS
and add a new user then delete your old one, make sure you give full admin rights for your new user account.